# Please help me identify this

Tags: identification, houseplants, propagation

[image]
My neighbor gave this to me right before she moved out of state she didn't know anything about it except that it would make a beautiful flowering plant. This is just the bottom of the start that I have It had been growing in a bowl of water long ways instead of stem down please help[image][image]

Comment: Hard to say what it is - first, it looks like a twining plant by the way the stems are wrapped around each other; second, hard to decide whether the rooty parts are actually roots or aerial roots; third, it appears to have some kind of infestation, there are some fuzzy white blobs on one of the leaves which might be insects (or not) and that crusty deposit doesn't look too healthy either. Anything odd underneath the leaves? Was this from an outdoor plant?

Comment: Thanks for noticing the condition of the leaves. I know absolutely nothing about this plant, except what was in my question. As far as underneath the leaves nothing unusual.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, it looks like it might be a Hoya. It appears from the picture the original grower may have been doing the braiding of the vines stems and they were using a bamboo stick to aid in the process. Easy to do with a Hoya vine.
Also Hoya have the most amazing flowers, but first it needs to be in a pot for a few years with its root undisturbed. Keep it in a fairly small pot.

Comment: Two hoya vines coming in contact and having nothing to climb on may eventually twist around each other like that, attempting to climb. I often untangle the Hoyas hanging under my pergola for that same reason. Otherwise, if I take one hanging pot, I may end-up pulling the whole row of pots... This may have happened without the bamboo stick, but right, Hoyas wrap around like these. The leaves appear as those of Hoya Carnosa.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with this piece of plant (and yes, it might be a Hoya) is its length and the fact that the rooty material is along the length. Added to that, if you're in the northern hemisphere, now is not really the time to start cuttings off this plant, its best done in spring and early summer. That said, we are where we are; I can only suggest that you cut it up in such a manner that you retain some of the rooty parts and a couple of leaves or a leaf, and either stand in a container of water with the roots down in the water and wait for fresh, new roots to appear, or try potting up the roots of a cut section, keeping the leaves above the soil, keep the cutting moist and hope it roots in properly. Cut off any bits of stem with neither leaf nor rooty growth at either end before trying this, as well as any of the twined stems with neither root nor leaf attached - you will have to untwine it carefully to do that. The extra, twined, stem material left sitting in water may just rot otherwise, and you'll lose the cutting. Further info on cuttings from Hoya here [How to Propagate Hoyas](https://theplanthunter.com.au/howto/propagating-hoyas-with-alan-and-jill/).